# RStudio install packages from Azure DevOps

Tags: r, azure-devops, rstudio, renv

I'm creating some internal packages with R in RStudio. My repositories are hosted in Azure DevOps. I saw the `renv.lock` and there is a section for repositories.

```
{
  "R": {
    "Version": "3.6.1",
    "Repositories": [
      {
        "Name": "CRAN",
        "URL": "https://cran.rstudio.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Packages": {
    "BH": {
      "Package": "BH",
      "Version": "1.69.0-1",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "0fde015f5153e51df44981da0767f522"
    },
    "KernSmooth": {
      "Package": "KernSmooth",
      "Version": "2.23-16",
      "Source": "Repository",
      "Repository": "CRAN",
      "Hash": "a531dc333440009ee13bbb507232476d"
    }
}
```

My components are in a url like

> https://dev.azure.com/mycompany/RComponents/_git/mycomponent

Is there a way to add my private repositories in here? How can I install R packages from Azure DevOps?

Comment: This is not currently supported. You can also file a feature request at https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues.

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work using the remotes package!

```
remotes::install_git("<clone url>", git = "external")

#AKA
remotes::install_git("https://ORG@dev.azure.com/USER/PROJECT/_git/NAME", git = "external")
```

You are then directed to a sign in handled via RStudio popups.

Answer (score 1):

renv is able to install and restore packages from a variety of sources, including:

- CRAN,
- Bioconductor,
- GitHub
- Gitlab
- Bitbucket

However, it does not include Azure DevOps. Please refer to [this document](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/renv.html#package-sources). In addition, there is also no information about using Azure DevOps repositories or packages in the [RStudio Documentation](https://docs.rstudio.com/).